# Сдампить названия функций и типы параметров из библиотеки

Tags: linux, windows, dll, library

Есть библиотека, но без документации. Хочется использовать её через dlopen, но не известны типы переменных.

Библиотека доступна в форматах PE и ELF.

```
ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, BuildID[sha1]=***, not stripped
```

Comment: Если эта библиотека предоставляет С интерфейс, то типы параметров по ней узнать не удастся.

Comment: как посмотреть очень сишная она или нет?

Comment: Посмотрите таблицу экспорта с помощью nm или CFF Explorer. Если имена у функций без крякозябров - значит С интерфейс.